# NUnit Test - Looping - C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, tdd, nunit

I am new to TDD and trying to solve a problem.

In my task, I have to read a bunch of strings from console and add them to a list of string type. In my test method, I have written a for loop to read strings and passing to a method to add. I don't know how to test this process, a bit confused. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Loop in the test method.

```
   for(int i=0;i<robot.noOfCommands;i++)
        {
            robot.readCommand(Console.ReadLine());

        }
```

I am writing code in C#.Net

Comment: what do you wanna test exactly? the number of strings in the list, the data in the strings or what?

Comment: number of strings and data in the strings

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unit tests should never require human interaction, so using Console.ReadLine() is a major no-no.

What you probably want, is to feed your `robot` object with some predefined input. Then you can test (`Assert`), that the outcome is what you expect. That is the essence of unit testing.

Answer (score 6):

In order for your test to work, you need to *fake* dependency on external service, which in this case is `System.Console`. Method you want to test (or class) need to have the ability to be provided with different types of this dependency - so that faked one can work too.

With `Console.ReadLine` what you really need is `TextReader`. Your looping method could look like this:

```
public void MyMethod(TextReader reader)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < robot.noOfCommands; i++)
    {
        robot.readCommand(reader.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

In real application, you will call it with `MyMethod(Console.In)`. In test, you can prepare fake reader (eg. reading from resource file) with predefined commands.

Comment: +1 for a beautifully simple method of faking Console! I never thought of this before. I'll be doing this in all my tests from now on.

Comment: This is a great solution for making Console input testable!