# Best way to unit test console c# app

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have a simple console app. It's fired of with a normal main and the entire program recides in main. It uses the [Command Line Parser Library](http://commandline.codeplex.com/). Then I have a second project in the solution containing unit tests for the application. But I don't seem to find a good way to start processes of the main program from the tests. My current code for actually start the process looks something like this.

```
...

process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "FooBar";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;

// use it to start from testing environment
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

// redirect outputs to have it in testing console
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

...
```

I have tried setting

```
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory
```

to

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

and

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory;
```

But do I have to specify the entire relative path for the console applications executable or is there a refined way of starting processes of the "tested" application?
First I had my tests as a class in the "main" program and then it worked just fine. The issues started when I moved the tests to their own project. That's why I suspect a path being the issue or something of that nature.

I also tried Running Program.Main but that just feels so wrong :)

Comment: I think it is better testing all the behavior in-process

Comment: What do you mean? Not having a separate project for tests?

Comment: You are not unit-testing, but end to end testing. Unit tests are on method-level.

Comment: @inquam I mean is better to do standard unit tests of your classes without calling the executable. This is more an integration test

Comment: Yes, I can agree with that. A regression test of sorts. But a simple console app that doesn't contain any other functions than main and not external classes is hard to test any other way ;)

Comment: Unbeknownst to this question, I created an example app that does exactly what you're asking. It's a console app using CommandLineParser but spreads out the code and is testable. https://github.com/ryanrodemoyer/JsonFormatterExample. The master branch has the code and stub unit tests so you can train yourself with unit testing. The answers branch has a full suite of unit tests using NUnit/Typemock (paid version).

Answer (score 21):

I would suggest restructuring your application into:

- `Program` - an entry point which parses the arguments, creating a `Settings` instance
- `Settings` - settings for the application (rename according to taste)
- `BusinessClass` - (definitely rename!) the actual work, which accepts a `Settings` instance

Now you can test things separately:

- Test the parsing into `Settings`, i.e. are you using the parser library correctly
- Your business logic, where the unit tests create appropriate instances of `Settings`

If possible, you should separate your business logic into separate classes for separate concerns of course, and test each separately. We don't really know enough to make concrete suggestions here.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why running Program.Main feels wrong for you. 
You're not supposed to unit-test the console mechanism.. only your program's logic, which you can easily do this way.

Comment: When I run the process to test the app I redirect output etc from that process so I can check for expected output depending on input. Also I check if the Process get's killed by receiving certain key combinations etc. how would I test this if running Main?

Comment: As other comments suggested, what I offered is unit-testing. If all your problem is the path, you can keep it statically