# Reading data from command line in c # when test driven by Nunit

Tags: c#, testing, nunit

I am using NUnit framework to run my test cases, and it works fine for me, but my requirement is I want to read some data from command line during running the test case. I have tried multiple options like using optionset and console.read and console.write, None of them works here as I believe Main function is mandatory for them. Please help me solve this as I am new to NUnit and C# .

Thanks,
Dattatraya

Comment: When unit testing, you shouldn't rely on input from the Console. You should be passing known inputs to the methods via NUnit and ensuring that for each known input, you get the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The case you describe is rather rare. As Justin said: You should [restructure your application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104429/best-way-to-unit-test-console-c-sharp-app), so you have separated layers to test.

Nevertheless your idea is senseful when doing User Acceptance Tests. In this case you may use the [`Console.SetIn()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setin%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to provide data for the input of your command line application.