# NUnit not loading latest version of a Console Application

Tags: c#-4.0, nunit, console-application

I am re-writing a console application and trying to use Unit Tests. I'm using NUnit, C#, .NET Framework 4 in Visual Studio 2010 on a Windows 7 PC.

When I change code within the application my unit tests don't pick up the latest changes. I can see that NUnit is reloading but for some reason it's not getting the latest version. The only way to get NUnit to work with the latest version is to remove the reference to the Console app, add it back and compile.

Is there a way to avoid doing this? I think the problem is that the the console app is compiled as an EXE, whereas with most applications I've unit-tested they have tended to be DLLs.

**EDIT**

I had hoped that this question: [Unit Testing a Console Application inside Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423267/unit-testing-a-console-application-inside-visual-studio) contained the answer. If you look at the accepted answer this was the way I'd been proceeding but my test project wasn't picking up the changes. I've now created a class library and I'm applying my tests to that. My console app will simply load, then call, this class library.

**Second Edit**

I've now got my code to a stage where I can test functionality and I've noticed the same problem with my console app. Although it 'says' it is referencing the compiled DLL, it only picks up the latest change when I delete and re-attach the reference. So, I'm thinking that the problem isn't necessarily connected to NUnit, rather an issue/quirk with console apps.

Comment: Which test runner do you use? Resharper, NUnit GUI, ...?

Comment: Just a guess: Maybe it's an issue with the shadow copy function of NUnit GUI. See `Menu > Tools > Settings > Test Loader > Advanced` and play around with the settings there.

Comment: Hi, I'll give it a go and let you know how I get on. I've got a few things to do this afternoon so it might be tomorrow before I give it a try.